# Shape change of buckled sheet under change of load

Tags: material-science, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I need to solve the following problem: a sheet of flexible but inextensible material (can be modelled as cable or chain in 2D) is fixed in endpoints and buckles up. Then a variable force is applied in one or more points. Under this force shape of the buckle changes because the sheet/chain/cable needs to preserve its length, it cannot compress or stretch. I need to compute numerically the shape of the buckle with and without force.

In my model I represent it as a chain, then I compute forces at both ends of each link. Force difference gives a rotating moment, so I rotate each link proportionally. However I cannot figure out how to constrain individual rotations so that the length of the chain is preserved. If each link has angle $\phi_i$, I need to fulfill $\sum(\cos(\phi_i))=A$ and $\sum(\sin(\phi_i))=0$, but that seems not trivial how to translate this into constraints on all $\phi_i$. Is there a method?
Or is there a whole different approach for solving this type of problems?

[image: buckled sheet]
[image: buckled and pressed sheet]

Comment: If all we consider is that the length must be preserved and the endpoints of the chain are fixed, then with the length shown between the endpoints shown in your photos, if the links are small enough we could rotate an individual link several full rotations, wrapping the rest of the chain in a spiral around that link. It seems to me this constraint on the angle is all but meaningless, as the kind of force shown will never cause such extreme rotation of a link. What is far more important is the fact that changing the angle between two links requires a bending force or torque.

Comment: I sort of agree. If we need to pack a length L between points X1 and X2, |X1-X2|<L, there is more than one way to do it, the fact that a real-world buckle looks like gaussian bell indicates that it minimises potential energy of the bending force, so I need to add it to the model. But I suppose I still need to have a length constraint somehow. Basically any force would cause a displacement of an element (e.g. chain link) in whatever degrees of freedom are available, provided constraints allow it. So I need to translate global constraint (cable length) to an element.

Comment: For each link, the distance between the two ends of the link is fixed. And the ends of the link are at the same positions as the near ends of the adjacent links. As long as you have those conditions, the total length is preserved.